# basic Symfony test drive failed - No route found for "GET /"

Tags: php, symfony

I like to test drive symfony with encore and twig enabled so i wrote this little windows batch file to download and start the server but i am keep getting errors.
- NotFoundHttpException
- ResourceNotFoundException
Did i miss something, like enabling twig exception handling and how can i enable that?

update: Empty framework doesn't do anything, 
added the LuckNumber example rom the documentation to the batch file

```
@echo off
set mypath=%~dp0
set me=%~n0

echo %mypath:~0,-1%
set project=%root%project
echo %project%

if not exist composer goto :nocomposer
if not exist nvm goto :nonvm
if not exist yarn goto :noyarn
if not exist git goto :nogit

if exist %project% goto :update

cmd.exe /c composer create-project symfony/skeleton project
::git clone https://github.com/Lyssal/flux.git
::xcopy flux\* %project% /t /e /i /q /y 
::rmdir flux /s /q

cd %project%
cmd.exe /c composer require server 
cmd.exe /c composer require sec-checker
cmd.exe /c composer require annotations
cmd.exe /c composer require profiler
cmd.exe /c composer require encore
cmd.exe /c composer require twig

    @echo ^<?php > src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo namespace App\Controller; >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route; >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller; >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo[  >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo class LuckyController extends Controller { >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo /** >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo * @Route^("/lucky/number"^) >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo */ >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo                          public function number^(^) { >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo                                          $number = mt_rand^(0, 100^); >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo                                          return $this-^>render('lucky/number.html.twig', array('number' =^> $number,)); >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo                          } >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    @echo   } >> src\Controller\LuckyController.php
    mkdir templates\lucky
    @echo {# templates/lucky/number.html.twig #}    > templates\lucky\number.html.twig
    @echo ^<h1^>Your lucky number is {{ number }}^</h1^> >> templates\lucky\number.html.twig

cmd.exe /c composer install
cmd.exe /c yarn install

echo ***********************************************************
echo    start your browser and type: localhost:8000/lucky/number
echo ***********************************************************
cmd.exe /c php bin/console server:run
pause
exit

:update
    cd %project%
    cmd.exe /c composer update
    cmd.exe /c yarn upgrade

    echo ***********************************************************
    echo    start your browser and type: localhost:8000/index.php
    echo ***********************************************************
    cmd.exe /c php bin/console server:run
    pause
    exit


:nonvm
    https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/
    echo install nvm-windows at https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/
    pause
    exit
:nocomposer
    echo install composer at https://getcomposer.org/
    pause
    exit
:noyarn
    echo install yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
    pause
    exit
:nogit
    echo install git at https://git-scm.com/download/win
    pause
    exit
```

Comment: If you take a look at config/routes.yaml you will notice that, out of the box, there are no routes defined.  Nor is there a controller.  For some reason, the powers that be set things up such that a standalone framework bundle will put up a status page without any routes actually defined.  But once you start adding stuff then it is up to you to add an actual route and controller.

Comment: thx - recreated the luck number example from the documentation and it works :)